# Excluir palavras repetidas de um array e ordena-lo

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma determinada função que me retorna *array* desordenado com várias cidades repetidas. Desta forma:

```
<?php 

function getArrayCities() {
    return array("são paulo","rio de janeiro","belo horizonte","recife","fortaleza",
   "porto alegre","jurerê","belo horizonte");
}

echo var_dump(getArrayCities());
```

Existe alguma função que exclui as cidade repetidas do *array* e sucessivamente ordena este mesmo *array*? Caso não haja, qual seria o método viável para este caso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para remover valores repetidos:

```
array_unique( $array );
```

Para ordenar:

```
sort( array &$array );
```

E ainda, se quiser ignorar maiúsculas e minúsculas, e considerar números pelo seu valor total e não pelos dígitos, tem esta:

```
natcasesort( array &$array );
```

Notar que o `array_unique` **retorna** o *array* sem os repetidos, mas o `sort` e `natcasesort` (assim como praticamente toda função de ordenação do PHP) ordenam o próprio *array* "in place" e retorna um booleano.

Ou seja, isso aqui não dá certo:

```
$ordenado = sort( $unico );
```

pelo simples fato do array não ser retornado pela função. A alteração é feita diretamente no `$unico` passado. (vale notar que na documentação, quando um parâmetro é prefixado por `&`, significa que é passado por referência, o que é um forte indicativo de que ele pode ser modificado no destino).

Para fazer as duas coisas, pode ser algo assim:

```
$cidades = array(
   'são paulo',
   'rio de janeiro',
   'belo horizonte',
   'recife',
   'fortaleza',
   'porto alegre',
   'jurerê',
   'belo horizonte'
);
$cidades = array_unique( $cidades );
natcasesort( $cidades );

// agora $cidades está em ordem e sem repetição
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/X1xQ5J)**.

### Internacionalização: usando UTF-8 e *collation*

Provavelmente você no dia a dia vai precisar de algo mais complexo, que ordene caracteres acentuados corretamente de acordo com a língua utilizada. Para estes cenários, o PHP tem uma coleção específica de funções:

> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.intl.php

A que nos interessa é o *Collator*. Veja um exemplo de uso:

```
$cidades = array_unique( $cidades );

$coll = collator_create( 'pt_BR' );
collator_sort( $coll, $cidades);
```

Comment: Legal. Mas o que seria "array 'in place'"?

Comment: @AckLay não fizemos $ordenado = sort( $unico ) pq não funciona assim. O sort mexe no array original, passado no parâmetro, em vez de retornar um novo.

Comment: Muitíssimo útil a parte do adicional "Internacionalização". Obrigado! Queria dar +2;